# how to load html file from sqlite3?

Tags: android, html, sqlite, webview

i have several html pages at sqlite3 which are connect with specific id. how can i dynamically load html from sqlite at runtime ?[image]

Comment: what means of html in sqlite3?how can you save html page in sqlite3?are you talking abt url as string in sqlite3?pls elaborate

Comment: Hi chirag, please take to look at to my sqlite image, i just save html files under description field and have to generate those html files with specific idx. any ideas ?

Comment: @chirag shah: HTML is just plain text, so he can save it in a text field. However, if the HTML contains images, he has a problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this by saving that html page tags all to one string, and then use method:

```
 txt.setText( Html.fromHtml(s));// where s is string which has your html page content
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use WebView's [`loadData`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html#loadData%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29) or [`loadDataWithBaseURL`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html#loadDataWithBaseURL%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29) methods to load the fetched text as HTML or you can save the fetched text as a HTML file then use [`loadURL`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html#loadUrl%28java.lang.String%29) method to load that file.